# Event handling: functional based component vs class based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, components

This is my very first React App (react@16.8.1
). I'm trying to find out why onClick event is handled differently when using functional based component vs class based component.

As I know, I should use class based c. only when I need to change state in it, am I right?

Functional based component throws an `_this is undefined error` but Class based - not.

I'm using arrow functions instead of bind function in both cases.

Functional based:

```
import React from 'react';

const AnswersDisplay = (props) => {
// even with bind I still get "_this is undefined"
//this.onAnswer = this.onAnswer.bind(this); 

  const answerList = props.answerList.map( (option) => {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={this.onAnswer}
        value={option}
        className="ui basic green button">{option}
      </button>
    )
  }); 

  const onAnswer = (e) =>{
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  return(
    <div className="ui two buttons hSpace">{this.answerList}</div>
  );
};

export default AnswersDisplay;
```

vs Class based that works.

```
import React from 'react';

class AnswersDisplay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //this.onAnswer = this.onAnswer.bind(this);
  }

  answerList = this.props.answerList.map( (option) => {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={this.onAnswer}
        value={option}
        className="ui basic green button">{option}
      </button>
    )
  });

  onAnswer = (e) =>{
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div className="ui two buttons hSpace">{this.answerList}</div>
    );
  }
};


export default AnswersDisplay;
```

Comment: `this` works differently in functional and class components, thus functions behave differently. Check how babel transpiles them

Comment: `this` in the function component doesn't refer to the component instance like it does in a class component. Try `onClick={onAnswer}` instead.

Comment: instead of `onClick={this.onAnswer}` use `onClick={onAnswer}`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, guys!

Comment: @ElenaJdanova an upvote to the answer will be helpful

Comment: I can't vote yet. Sorry @ Haider Ali Anjum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of functional components, you are declaring a constant, holding a function inside it. Which you want to call in case of a click on the button. But make sure the usage of  `this` in a function. `this` will refer to the global execution context in this case, and in that particular context, the JavaScript engine will fail to find a property `onAnswer` so it will return `undefined`.

Just to make this work you have pass the call back without `this`.

> Like that: `onClick={onAnswer}`

As a whole the code will look like following:

```
import React from 'react';

const AnswersDisplay = (props) => {
// even with bind I still get "_this is undefined"
//this.onAnswer = this.onAnswer.bind(this); 

  const answerList = props.answerList.map( (option) => {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={onAnswer}
        value={option}
        className="ui basic green button">{option}
      </button>
    )
  }); 

  const onAnswer = (e) =>{
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  return(
    <div className="ui two buttons hSpace">{this.answerList}</div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This [MDN web doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) covers everything you'll need to know about `this`.

To keep it simple, think of in terms of `objects`, where `this` is "undefined" unless:

- The method/function has been bound to the `object` with ES5's `bind(this)` (see note below) OR rebound outside the `object` by rebinding an outside function with the `object` itself: `bind(obj)`.

**Note**: As demonstrated below (in method6), there's an exception where using ES5 `arrow functions` inside of the `object` means it'll retain the enclosing lexical scoped `this` without needing to be bound.

For Example:

```js
this.prop = "global prop"
const outsideArrowFunction = () => (this.prop)

function outsideFunction() {
    return this.prop;
};

const obj = {
  prop: "obj's prop",
  method: function() {
    return this.prop; // returns "obj's prop"
  },
  method2: function() {
    return this; // returns the entire "obj" and its properties
  },
  method3: function() {
    return this.method(); // returns "obj's prop"
  },
  method4: function() {
    return outsideFunction(); // returns "global prop" because the outsideFunction's lexical scope doesn't recognize the "obj"'s nor its properties      
  },
  method5: function() {
    return outsideArrowFunction(); // same as method4, utilizes global this
  },
  method6: function() {
    const x = () => this.method();
    return x(); // returns "obj's prop" because arrow functions take on "this" from the "obj"
  },
  method7: function() {
    const x = function() { 
       return this.prop; 
    };
    return x(); // returns "global prop" because "this" loses lexical scope upon execution
  },
  method8: function() {
   const x = this.method.bind(this);
   return x(); // returns "obj's prop" because "this" refers to the "obj" upon execution
  },
  method9: function(callback) {
    return callback(this.method);
  },
  method10: function() {
    return this.method9(function(callback) {
      return callback(); // returns "global prop" because "this" loses lexical scope upon execution
    });
  }
}; 


const a = outsideArrowFunction.bind(obj); // returns "global prop" because arrow functions take on whatever "this" is upon its creation, so "this" refers to the global "this"
const b = outsideFunction.bind(obj); // returns "obj's prop" since a traditional function can rebind "this", which has been rebound to "obj"   
    
console.log(`Method: ${obj.method()}`);
console.log(`Method2: ${obj.method2()}`);
console.log(`Method3: ${obj.method3()}`);
console.log(`Method4: ${obj.method4()}`);
console.log(`Method5: ${obj.method5()}`);
console.log(`Method6: ${obj.method6()}`);
console.log(`Method7: ${obj.method7()}`);
console.log(`Method8: ${obj.method8()}`);
console.log(`Method10: ${obj.method10()}`);
console.log(`arrowFunction: ${a()}`);
console.log(`outsideFunction: ${b()}`);
```

When it comes to `classes`, they're a template of `objects`. So `this` will be `undefined` or be a global `this` unless the class `method` has been bound in the `constructor` or you use an `arrow function`. Try out the example below by clicking on each of the buttons, notice how all 3 methods **can** work but it **depends on how they were called**:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { method: "" };
    this.boundMethod = this.boundMethod.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    this.unboundMethod(); 
  };

  boundMethod() {
    this.setState({ method: "Bound Method" }); // this works because the method is bound to the class
  }

  unboundMethod() {
    try {
      this.setState({ method: "Unbound Method" }); // this only works if it's called within a bound method class (like componentDidMount)
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err); // however, if it's called within a callback (like in an onClick event), it fails.
    }
  }

  arrowMethod = () => {
    this.setState({ method: "Arrow Method" }); // this works because arrow methods are automatically bound to the class
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.boundMethod}>Bound Method</button>
        <button onClick={this.unboundMethod}>Unbound Method</button>
        <button onClick={this.arrowMethod}>Arrow Method</button>
        <p>The {this.state.method} was called</p>
     </div>
    );
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```